# How to count sum of people for each country? Python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I'm new at python. I struggle how to count how many people have died from each country. I use pandas dataframe. 0 - means that person died, 1 - survived. I have ~2000rows.
Maybe it is not enough info, but I dont know how to solve this and from what exactly to start...

```
df['survived'] = df['survived'].replace(['no'], 0)
df['survived'] = df['survived'].replace(['yes'], 1)

countries_list = list(df['country'])
survived_list = list(df['survived'])

for i in range(len(survived_list)):
        print(f'{survived_list[i]}: {countries_list[i]}')
```

I only get to this point and dont know what to do. With IF statement I also get nowhere:
If i write like this (below) it shows me an error I dont know why. I hope that you get the idea what I want to do. Thank you in advance

```
if survived_list == 0:
```

0: United States
0: United States
0: United States
1: England
1: Norway
1: United States
0: France
1: France
1: Lebanon
1: Finland
0: Sweden
0: England
...

Comment: Did you mean `if len(survived_list) == 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
counts = {}

for i in range(len(survived_list)):
    try:
        counts[countries_list[i]] += survived_list[i]
    except:
        counts[countries_list[i]] = survived_list[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

"How to count how many people have died from each country" ?

Why do you get lists back from your dataframe to do some computations in pure Python ?
Pandas dataframes are made for that kind of computation.

```py
df["died"] = df["survived"].map(lambda x: 1 if x==0 else 0)
df.groupby(['country']).sum()
```